# Variation in marker text sizes within the Scatter3d chart of Plotly.js

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I'm trying to put together a simple 3D scatter chart using Plotly.js with some dummy data thrown in for good measure. I've got the markers all set up to interact with text above them, triggered by either clicking on a data point or using the Left and Right arrow keys.

Everything's groovy except for one glitch: when I hit the Right arrow key for the first time, the text size above that specific marker is bigger. It's different from the text sizes of all the other data points.

If you're up for it, check out the CodePen demo: [Demo Link](https://codepen.io/deepak-techprescient/pen/ZEPJKOG)

Any ideas on how to fix this text size hiccup would be awesome!

I attempted to address the problem by setting `textfont.size` for each marker, but unfortunately, I didn't get the expected result. I'm struggling to make the size of the text above the marker consistent for all data points.

Steps to Reproduce:

- Load the chart.
- Press the Right arrow key and observe the text size.
- Press the Left arrow key and compare the sizes again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.